# Sorting multidimensional array without sort method?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I was tasked with creating a 2D array (10-by-10), filling it with random numbers (from 10 to 99), and other tasks. I am, however, having difficulty sorting each row of this array in ascending order without using the array sort() method.

My sorting method does not sort. Instead, it prints out values diagonally, from the top leftmost corner to the bottom right corner. What should I do to sort the numbers?

Here is my code:

```
public class Program3 
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int[][] arrayOne = new int[10][10];
        int[][] arrayTwo = new int[10][10];
        arrayTwo = fillArray(arrayOne);

        System.out.println("");

        looper(arrayTwo);

        System.out.println("");

        sorter(arrayTwo);


    }
    public static int randomRange(int min, int max)
    {
        // Where (int)(Math.random() * ((upperbound - lowerbound) + 1) + lowerbound);
        return (int)(Math.random()* ((max - min) + 1) + min);
    }
    public static int[][] fillArray(int x[][])
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < x.length; row++)
        {
            for (int column = 0; column < x[row].length; column++)
            {
                x[row][column] = randomRange(10,99);
                System.out.print(x[row][column] + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        return x;
    }
    public static void looper(int y[][])
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < y.length; row++)
        {
            for (int column = 0; column < y[row].length; column++)
            {
                if (y[row][column]%2 == 0)
                {
                    y[row][column] = 2 * y[row][column];

                    if (y[row][column]%10 == 0)
                    {
                        y[row][column] = y[row][column]/10;

                    }
                }
                else if (y[row][column] == 59)
                {
                    y[row][column] = 99;
                }
                System.out.print(y[row][column] + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        //return y;
    }
    public static void sorter(int[][] z)
    {
        int temp = 0;
        int tempTwo = 0;
        int lowest; 
        int bravo = 0;
        int bravoBefore = -1;

        for (int alpha = 0; alpha < z.length; alpha++)
        {
            //System.out.println(alpha + "a");

            lowest = z[alpha][bravoBefore + 1];
            bravoBefore++;
            for (bravo = alpha + 1; bravo < z[alpha].length; bravo++)
            {
                //System.out.println(alpha + "b");
                temp = bravo;

                if((z[alpha][bravo]) < lowest)
                {

                    temp = bravo;
                    lowest = z[alpha][bravo];
                    //System.out.println(lowest + " " + temp);
                    //System.out.println(alpha + "c" + temp);
                    tempTwo = z[alpha][bravo];
                    z[alpha][bravo] = z[alpha][temp];
                    z[alpha][temp] = tempTwo;   
                    //System.out.println(alpha + "d" + temp);
                }

            }

            System.out.print(z[alpha][bravoBefore] + "\t");
        }
        /*
        for (int alpha = 0; alpha < z.length; alpha++)
        {
            for (int bravo = 0; bravo < z.length - 1; bravo++)
            {
                if(Integer.valueOf(z[alpha][bravo]) < Integer.valueOf(z[alpha - 1][bravo]))
                {
                    int[][] temp = z[alpha - 1][bravo];
                    z[alpha-1][bravo] = z[alpha][bravo];
                    z[alpha][bravo] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
         */
    }
}
```

Comment: There are lots of things wrong.  A big one: what will `z[alpha][bravo] = z[alpha][temp];` do, given that `temp` will always be equal to `bravo`?  If you want to sort the numbers in the whole row, why does your inner loop start at `alpha + 1`?  That will skip a bunch of numbers.  Also, is your sorter supposed to be printing anything?  If so, what?  You go through the rows and only print one number from each row.

Comment: @ajb I made the array with the intention of having (as an example) two values, int a = 100 and int b = 85, and a temp. If a < b, b gets put into temp, a gets put into b, and the original b gets put into a. As for why the inner loop starts at alpha + 1, I was hoping to look at the next number in the row (so that I could sort it). Yes, my sorter is supposed to print something, a new array in fact. I messed up, however, but I added in a new line to fix it.

Comment: The next number in which row?  Your outer loop goes through each row.  When the inner loop starts, you're looking at a new row that you haven't looked at before.  So don't you want to start with the first element in that new row?  The way you've written it, when you look at `z[5]`, you start by looking at `z[5][5]`.  Your program never looks at `z[5][0]`, `z[5][1]`, ..., `z[5][4]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int k = 0; k < arr.length; k++)
        {
            for(int p = 0; p < arr[k].length; p++)
            {
                least = arr[k][p];
                for(int i = k; i < arr.length; i++)
                {
                    if(i == k)
                        z = p + 1;
                    else
                        z = 0;
                    for(;z < arr[i].length; z++)
                    {
                        if(arr[i][z] <= small)
                        {
                            least = array[i][z];
                            row = i;
                            col = z;
                        }
                    }
                }
            arr[row][col] = arr[k][p];
            arr[k][p] = least;
            System.out.print(arr[k][p] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
```

Hope this code helps . Happy coding

Comment: Is `least` an integer?

Comment: yes when the values in 2d array are int it is int if its double its double your choice here least is smallvalue in comparision

Comment: Where do you define `least,` `z,` `small,` `row,` and `col.`

Comment: Before the very first for loop?

Comment: yes the beauty of java is you can define at particular instance you need also.Brandon please read the basics in java looks like you are a starter.There is more to go.Keep on coding.good luck

Answer (score 0):

let x is our unsorted array;

```
        int t1=0;
        int i1=0;
        int j1=0;
        int n=0;

        boolean f1=false;

        for(int i=0;i<x.length;i++){

            for(int j=0;j<x[i].length;j++){

                t1=x[i][j];



                for(int m=i;m<x.length;m++){


                    if(m==i)n=j+1;  

                    else n=0;   

                    for(;n<x[m].length;n++){

                        if(x[m][n]<=t1){

                            t1=x[m][n];
                            i1=m;
                            j1=n;
                            f1=true;
                        }                       

                    }


                }

                if(f1){ 
                    x[i1][j1]=x[i][j];
                    x[i][j]=t1;
                    f1=false;
                }
            }   


        }
```

//now x is sorted; "-";